# WordPress вывод Социальных иконок в определенном порядке

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте знатоки Wordpress. 
Я только начинаю постигать основы PHP и Wordpress и сейчас столкнулся с такой делемой. Я вывожу соц. иконки через шорткод **[alx-social id="Vk,Twitter"]** в id записываю названия соц сети. Если в БД она есть то выводим её.
Не могу сделать так что бы они выводились в том порядке в котором они записаны, они выводятся по какому то своему порядку.

Вот функция шорткода

```
// Вывод социальных иконок ШОРТКОД

function alx_social($attr,$text=''){
//Глобальный массив опций
    global $options;

// Получаем массив данных из атрибутов шорткода и превращаем их в массив
    $razbienie = explode(',', $attr['id']);

// Преобразуем все элементы массива в нижний регистр
    $razbienie = array_map('strtolower', $razbienie);

?>

<!--Помещаем иконки в отдельный блок-->
<div class="alx-socials">

<?php

// Перебераем Массив опций и массив из шорткода если есть совпадения выводим их значение
    foreach($options as $key => $value1){
        foreach($razbienie as $value2){
            if ($key == $value2){

                switch($key){
                    case 'twitter':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["twitter"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'facebook':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["facebook"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'instagram':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["instagram"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'vk':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["vk"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'youtube':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["youtube"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'google':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["google"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'pinterest':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["pinterest"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'flickr':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["flickr"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-flickr" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                    case 'linkedin':
                        echo '<a href="'. $options["linkedin"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                    break;

                } // end switch
            }// end if
        }// end forech 2
    }// end foreach 1
?>
</div>  <!--end .alx-socials-->

<?php

}

add_shortcode('alx-social', 'alx_social');
```

За ранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы так должно работать. Изменил цикл вывода соц.сетей в div

```
<?php

//Перебираем принятые названия соцсетей
foreach($razbienie as $social_name){
    //Если соц.сеть существует в массиве $options то выводим её.
    if (array_key_exists($social_name, $options)){

        switch($social_name){
            case 'twitter':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["twitter"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'facebook':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["facebook"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'instagram':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["instagram"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'vk':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["vk"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'youtube':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["youtube"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'google':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["google"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'pinterest':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["pinterest"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-pinterest-p" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'flickr':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["flickr"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-flickr" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

            case 'linkedin':
                echo '<a href="'. $options["linkedin"] .'"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>';
                break;

        } // end switch
    }// end if
}// end foreach

?>
```